# reading a text file,arranging it according a number of specific characters to assign html tags

Tags: python, readline

i am need help designating the  number of string characters my python code should read up to so i can assign an html tag to it so as as to easily copy paragraphs to from sources to be easily arranged with the

tag added in addition. my code works just that i does half of the job which is assigning the tags to   and write to specified file but , i want it to be able to pick any long line and arrange it in a specified number of characters for each line ,

for eg : in the inputfile.txt contains 
         this text:  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec consequat tellus, vel rutrum justo."

the outputfile.txt should read 1st line : "

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing

" 
2nd line should read : "

elit. Vivamus nec consequat tellus, vel rutrum justo.

"

```
def add_anytag():



    z=None
    m=None




    with open("inputfile.txt",'r+') as infile,open("outputfile.txt","w+") as outfile:
        while  None in (z,m) :
            m = infile.readline()
            z=len(m)
            while z>0  :
                m="<p>"+ m + "</p>" + "\n"

                print (m, file = outfile)
                print (m)
                m=infile.readline()
                z=len(m)

    print ("please your file is ready , do  locate your file as outputfile.txt")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear what you are asking for. Are you trying to break up lines? When you are writing HTML, you might want to avoid breaking up lines, as this will prevent the browser from being able to reformat the code to fit its shape.

Comment: okay let me try that out , by allowing the browser to do it

Comment: cool it makes sense my code was sufficient thanks